# creating a linked list in assembly language 8086

Tags: assembly, linked-list, x86, x86-16

Can you read and write data/strings in specific memory locations/addresses? im planning to make a linked list in 8086 but i dont know how to read data from specific memory addresses and how to store data in different memory address using the same variable. is this possible? if yes, how?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. What's the alternative? Write "just anywhere randomly"?

Comment: using arrays is the alternative, but im just wondering if this is possible in 8086

Comment: Arrays are just a special case of reading and writing anywhere you feel like, they begin anywhere you feel like and they have an index that's anything you feel like - there are no actual arrays, it's just a bunch of memory that you use in a specific way to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could link the element like this:

```
jmp start
element0 db 10
element1 db "jsdafélasjfdélasjd"
element2 db "lkjfasljf"
element3 db 12, 34
element4 db  "asfd"
;etc.
links:
dw element0
dw element1
dw element2
dw element3
dw element4
start:
push cs
pop ds
lea si, links
add si, (3*2)
;si is now set to the offset of element3
```

If the program will insert new elements, it would be important to leave enough place after the end of the list.

Comment: do you have a link about how to use links? im quite new to that instruction

Comment: A link is an offset of the beginning of a string or a number.

Everytime, when you want to output a string which is stored in a variable, you have to load the 

offset before (in most compiler it's the command       "mov si, offset nameofthevariable"         

or

       "lea si, nameofthevariable"     

The offset is the number of the place in memory where the variable is stored. To read a 

variable we use the register si and to store a variable we use the register di. The offset is 

always a fixed place in the own segment.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, for example

```
mov di, [di]
mov di, [di]
```

Advances a couple of places through a linked list where the `next` link is the first thing in the node (if it isn't, add a constant offset).

A larger problem here is allocating and deallocating those nodes.